# Autolayout issue for UIImageView in UIScrollView (XIB)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout

So, the scenario is like this:

1. I can only use XIB's (cannot use storyboards, and interestingly, this problem is not there when working with storyboards :/ ).
2. I cannot use Autoresizing since the main project I am building on NEEDS autolayout as of now.

Please find my sample project here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5p6wynl15kgaxok/AAAwiXeTJnD4yJKjOIZdywEza?dl=0

Though it seems like I have the constraints set up correctly, it is showing content ambiguity problem. When as a workaround I tried adding some more constraints (like Horizontal Center and Vertical centre), the warning does go away, but the imageview doesn't get zoomed when I try the same in iPad device running on iOS 7.1.2 (there is no issue on the latest ones). And, I have replicated the same issue on multiple devices.

How can get around this problem to solve the problem in such a way that the iPad problem doesn't come up.

The same constraints, when given to a similar setup in Storyboards, doesn't have this issue. But unfortunately, I cannot switch to storyboards now. :(

Comment: It seems like the URL is not valid anymore. Maybe you could post the code you use to setup the constraints?

Comment: Sorry. I had accidentally moved that folder. The link is up again. Please do check. And, I don't have any constraints set up programmatically. Everything's been setup via the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue when working with **XIB** + **Auto-layout** + **UIImageView inside UIScrollView** + **iOS 7.1.2** (or maybe iOS 7.x or 7.1.x).

*Probably*, the only way around to solve this issue might be to not use any one or more of the 4 above factors (which obviously beats the user's freedom or purpose). :/

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by image view does not get zoomed? 
I can see the image like in the attachment.[image]

Comment: I meant that the imageview doesn't get zoomed when we pinch out (issue only on iPad running 7.1.2). It is working fine in iPads and iPhones running on iOS 8 and above.